# How to show Spark application's percentage of completion on AWS EMR (and Boto3)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am running a Spark step on AWS EMR, this step is added to EMR through Boto3, I will like to return to the user a percentage of completion of the task, is there anyway to do this?

I was thinking to calculate this percentage with the number of completed stages of Spark, I know this won't be too precise, as the stage 4 may take double time than stage 5 but I am fine with that.

Is it possible to access this information with boto3?

I checked the method `list_steps` ([here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.list_steps) are the docs) but in the response I am getting only if its running without other information.

Answer (score 2):

**DISCLAIMER**: I know nothing about AWS EMR and Boto3

> I will like to return to the user a percentage of completion of the task, is there anyway to do this?

*Any way?* Perhaps. Just register a [SparkListener](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener) and intercept events as they come. That's how web UI works under the covers (which is the definitive source of truth for Spark applications).

Use `spark.extraListeners` property to register a `SparkListener` and do whatever you want with the events.

Quoting the official documentation's [Application Properties](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties):

> **spark.extraListeners** A comma-separated list of classes that implement `SparkListener`; when initializing `SparkContext`, instances of these classes will be created and registered with Spark's listener bus. If a class has a single-argument constructor that accepts a `SparkConf`, that constructor will be called; otherwise, a zero-argument constructor will be called.

You could also consider [REST API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api) interface:

> In addition to viewing the metrics in the UI, they are also available as JSON. This gives developers an easy way to create new visualizations and monitoring tools for Spark. The JSON is available for both running applications, and in the history server. The endpoints are mounted at /api/v1. Eg., for the history server, they would typically be accessible at http://:18080/api/v1, and for a running application, at http://localhost:4040/api/v1.

Comment: This is a very nice approach but I think that there will be an overhead in development if you want to use boto3 for this. The AWS API isn't much friendly for these kind of actions. You get my vote anyway !

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported at the moment and I don't think it will be anytime soon.

You'll just have to follow application logs the old fashioned way. So maybe consider formatting your logs in a way you know what has actually finished.